# Setting up forgotten password reset link (MERN stack)

Tags: node.js, reactjs, authentication, routes, mern

I'm working on a project, where I have implemented an API for logging in and registering users. Everything works for me...except one thing: the forgot password feature. In that case, when I click the link that is sent to my email address, I get a blank screen and a console error about mime types. The error is: Refused to apply style from 'http://localhost:3000/passwordreset/index.css' because its MIME type ('text/html') is not a supported stylesheet MIME type, and strict MIME checking is enabled.

What I should get instead is a React component with username, password, and confirm password fields. But it won't display when I click the link in the email.

Even worse...now the error itself disappeared (not sure what I did), and the component (PasswordReset.jsx) still won't render.

I've verified and reverified the routes, query params, and so on...any thoughts?

Answer (score 1):

Nevermind! I mistakenly had a route with a query param, but missing a '/' character. So, I had:

```
 <Route
     exact
     path="/passwordreset:resetToken"
     component={PasswordResetScreen}
 />
```

instead of:

```
 <Route
     exact
     path="/passwordreset/:resetToken"
     component={PasswordResetScreen}
 />
```